# Ubuntu 12.10 just Killed Wine & ZSNES

Tags: upgrade, wine, zsnes

My system just did a partial upgrade. I was busy doing something else so just let it get on with things.

Now it has removed Wine and ZSNES and won't allow me to reinstall them! Is there a way to "roll back" to before this stupid partial upgrade?

Comment: OK, I've gone into my software sources and changed my UK server to the main server and have been able to reinstall Wine and ZSNES.

I read the sticky on the Ubuntu forums about partial upgrades and won't be allowing anymore of those to run lol.

Lesson learned.

Pete.

Comment: Close voters: This should not be closed as *too localized*, only as a duplicate (if applicable). @Badderspj You seem to have found the answer. Please post it as an answer to your own question. (When there's no other satisfactory answer and you've found the it, [we encourage this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).) 2 days after posting it, you can accept your own answer (by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it). This will make clear that your problem is solved, and also help others searching for solutions to this or similar problems.